# Asynchronously bundles

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I’m working on page load performance - mainly focusing on javascript. My question is about asynchronously specific 'bundles'. I’ve got some JS modules that could, in theory, be loaded async, however, I don’t quite know the best approaching for organizing synchronous and async bundles, and how to correctly define dependencies. I'm referring to the pattern also known as 'lazy loading'.

For example, I've got a **typeahead module** that fetches data `getItems` and then gives the user suggestions as they type into an input field. When the user types an input that **doesn't** match any of the data `handleNoResults` is called, it returns a message *'could not match input'*. This message needs to be translated into various languages, depending on what locale is currently set.

I don't want to load the entire JS translation script, that allows me to translate the text, until it's necessary, as it's a pretty big file and really hampers performance - I want to load it when it's actually needed - i.e when the user has initial clicked in the input field, it could then be fetched.

**typeahead.js - pseudo example**

```
export default function Typeahead(element) {
  init.call(this);

  function init() {
    var input = element.getElementsByTagName('input')[0];
    if (input) {
      getItems.call(this);
    }
  }

  function getItems() {
    $.get('/search_answers.json', function (result) {
      items = result;
    });
  }

  function handleNoResults() {
    return I18n.t('js.typeahead_no_results');
  }
}
```

Any advice or direction towards some es6 patterns for managing this type of solution would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: The question has little chances to be reopened. Once it's closed, a new improved question should be answered. However, I'm not sure if this should be done. *a pretty big file and really hampers performance* - not true. A single *asynchronous* script generally loads faster than a bunch of them, and HTTP2 isn't supported everywhere. Unless you did tests, you can go with fewer bundles as a rule of thumb (some - not 10s or 100s). Making a fine-grained bundles for almost each message l10n is absolute overkill, both in terms of data transmission and human efforts.

Comment: More importantly, nothing suggests that this should be achieved with JS modules, bundled or not. Localized messages are text data. They can be transmitted as regular JSON (again, this doesn't mean that sending them in fine-grained chunks will be effective, performance should be tested). The example doesn't have anything to do with the question and suggests that it's XY problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JavaScript itself don't have the concept of bundles. Native ES modules (in browsers where they are implemented) can be loaded dynamically (and also asynchronously) with `import()`, which is [stage 3 proposal](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-dynamic-import) and has [limited support in browsers](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/11/dynamic-import).

You should address this with solution you chose for bundling like Webpack. It has advanced features for [code splitting](https://webpack.js.org/guides/code-splitting/) and also supports [`import()`](https://webpack.js.org/guides/code-splitting/#dynamic-imports).